# Need a regex to split the string based on @ which does not split if it has \\ in front of it, some thing like this \\@ in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to split the string based on the @ but it should not split if it has \ in front of the @

input :

```
Email@Test@SAMLE DATA@test\\@gmail.com
```

output :

```
    Email
    Test
    SAMLE DATA
    test@gmail.com
```

please help on this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try splitting on the regex pattern `(?<!\\)@`, which splits on `@` provided that it is *not* preceded by a backslash.  Sample Perl script:

```
$input = 'Email@Test@SAMLE DATA@test\\@gmail.com'; 
@parts = split('(?<!\\\\)@', $input); 
foreach $i (@parts) {
    print "$i\n"; 
}
```

This prints:

```
Email
Test
SAMLE DATA
test\@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Above solution is good. To get more information on Negative Lookbehind(?<!pattern) check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-assertions-in-regex/  I have just added string replace condition in order to get result as test@gmail.com. List::MoreUtils provides some trivial but commonly needed functionality on lists which is not going to go into List::Util.
Please check https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils

> Script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(apply);
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $str = 'Email@Test@SAMLE DATA@test\\@gmail.com';
# apply : Applies BLOCK to each item in LIST and returns a list of the values
# after BLOCK has been applied. In scalar context, the last element is returned. 
#This function is similar to map but will not modify the elements of the 
#input list
# split method returns list and in apply checking if string contain \\ replace it.
my @words = apply { s/\\//g } split(/(?<!\\)@/, $str);
print Dumper(\@words);
```

> Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Email',
          'Test',
          'SAMLE DATA',
          'test@gmail.com'
        ];
```